# getline not getting first token

Tags: c++, csv, ifstream, getline

I'm trying to read a CSV file, the problem is that every time the program reads a line and tries to split it by commas, it apparently skips the first token. Why is this?

```
void readCSV(string path) {
    ifstream file;
    string line, cell;
    stringstream ss;
    
    file.open(path);
    if (file.fail()) {
        throw runtime_error("Cannot read file");
    }

    while (getline(file, line)) {
        ss << line;
        while (getline(ss, cell, ',')) {
            cout << cell << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
        ss.str(string());
        ss.clear();
    }
    
    file.close();
}
```

CSV file content:

```
a,b,c,d,e
1,2,3,4,5
```

Output:

```
  b c d e
  2 3 4 5
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. Your code works fine for me.

Comment: are you sure that there are no spaces in the input file? (though this would produce different output)

Comment: It looks fine to me. Are you sure this is the code you are running? Did you make some changes and forgot to compile?

Comment: You should try to debug your code and see step-by-step what are the values in your variables, if you're on windows using Visual Studio you can use the built-in debugger, and on Linux you can use GDB/LLDB.